# IronPython: StartThread creates 'DummyThreads' that don't get cleaned up

Tags: multithreading, ironpython

The problem I have is that in my IronPython application threads are being created but never cleaned up, even when the method they run has exited. In my application I start threads in two ways: a) by using Python-style threads (sub-classes of threading.Thread that do something in their run() method), and b) by using the .NET 'ThreadStart' approach. The Python-style threads behave as expected, and after their 'run()' exits they get cleaned up. The .NET style threads never get cleaned up, even after they have exited. You can call del, Abort, whatever you want, and it has no effect on them.

The following IronPython script demonstrates the issue:

```
import System
import threading
import time
import logging

def do_beeps():
    logging.debug("starting do_beeps")
    t_start = time.clock()
    while time.clock() - t_start < 10:
        System.Console.Beep()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000)
    logging.debug("exiting do_beeps")

class PythonStyleThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_name="PythonStyleThread"):
        super(PythonStyleThread, self).__init__(name=thread_name)

    def run(self):
        do_beeps()

class ThreadStarter():

    def start(self):
        t = System.Threading.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart(do_beeps))
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Name = "ThreadStartStyleThread"
        t.Start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

    # Start some ThreadStarter threads:
    for _ in range(5):
        ts = ThreadStarter()
        ts.start()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(200)

    # Start some Python-style threads:
    for _ in range(5):
        pt = PythonStyleThread()
        pt.start()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(200)

    # Do something on the main thread:
    for _ in range(30):
        print(".")
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000)
```

When this is debugged in PyDev, what I see is that all the threads appear as expected in the 'debug' view as they are created:

[image: all threads in pydev debugger]

but whereas the Python-style ones disappear after they've finished, the .NET / ThreadStart ones stay until the main thread exits.

[image: lingering threads in pydev debugger]

As can be seen in the image, in the debugger the problematic threads appear with names 'Dummy-4', 'Dummy-5' etc, whereas the Pythonic ones appear with the name I've given them ('PythonStyleThread'). Looking in the threading.py file in my IronPython installation I see there is a class called "_DummyThread", a subclass of Thread, that sets its 'name' as 'name=_newname("Dummy-%d")', so it looks like by using ThreadStart I'm ending up with _DummyThreads. The comment for the class also says:

```
# Dummy thread class to represent threads not started here.
# These aren't garbage collected when they die, nor can they be waited for.
```

which would explain why I can't get rid of them.

But I don't want 'DummyThread's. I just want normal ones, that behave nicely and get garbage-collected when they've finished doing their thing.

Now, a slightly odd thing about all of this is that unless I set up the logger I don't see the DummyThread entries in the debugger at all (although they still run). This may be a funny of the PyDev debugger, or it may relevant. Is there any sane reason why logging should have any bearing on this? Can I solve my problem just by not logging in my thread?

[Here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython-docs/blob/master/library/threading.rst), it says:

> "There is the possibility that "dummy thread objects" are created. These are thread objects corresponding to "alien threads", which are threads of control started outside the threading module, such as directly from C code. Dummy thread objects have limited functionality; they are always considered alive and daemonic, and cannot be `join`ed. They are never deleted, since it is impossible to detect the termination of alien threads."

Which makes me wonder why I've had the misfortune of ending up with them?

While I have a workaround in that I can use Python-style threading.Thread subclasses everywhere I currently use .NET 'ThreadStart' threads, I am not keen to do this as the reason I was using .NET style threads in certain places was because they give me an `Abort` method (whereas the Python ones don't). I know Aborting threads is a Bad Thing, but the application is a unit-testing framework, and I a) need to run unit-tests in a thread, and b) have no control over their contents (they are written by third-parties), so I have no means of periodically checking for a 'please shut me down nicely' flag on these threads, and in extremis may need to kill them rudely.

So a) why am I getting DummyThreads, b) has this got anything to do with logging and c) what can I do about it?

Thanks.